# laravel upload_max_filesize limit is 0 KiB linux

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, upload-max-filesize

I try upload file with 4MB,
but e receveid error with message:
`"The file "Faturamento.pbit" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 0 KiB)."`

in my `phpinfo()` has this values:

> upload_max_filesize | 100MB | 100MB
>
> memory_limit      | 128M  | 128M
>
> max_file_uploads  | 20    | 20

my blade input:

```html
@extends('system.system', ['activePage' => __($pageInfos['activeTag']), 'activeSubPage' => __($pageInfos['activeSubTag']), 'titlePage' => __($pageInfos['title'])])

{{-- @extends('system.system') --}}

{{--  CSS --}}
@section('HeaderCss')
    <link href="{{ mix('css/powerbi/document.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
@stack('styles')
@endsection

{{--  CONTEUDO --}}
@section('content')

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form action="makedocument" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        @component('system.partials._cardWithIcone', ['icone' =>'fas fa-file', 'cardTitle' => 'Arquivo',
        'footerCenter' => true])
        @slot('slot1')
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label class="form-label d-none" for="pbit_file">Arquivo Pbit</label>
                    <span class="btn btn-green btn-round btn-file col-md-12">
                        <span class="fileinput-new">Select .PBIT</span>
                        <input type="file" id="pbit_file" name="pbit_file">
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        @endslot
        @slot('slot2')
        @endslot
        @endcomponent
    </div>
</div>
@endsection

{{--  JAVASCRIPT --}}
@section('FooterScript')
@parent
<script src="{{ mix('js/powerbi/document.js') }}" defer></script>
@endsection
```

where receive mthe file:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\PowerBI;

//use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use ZipArchive;

class PowerBIController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function document()
    {
        return view("system.powerbi.document")->with([
            "pageInfos" => [
                "title" => "Gerar Documentação",
                "activeTag" => "PowerBI", //Tag de ativar a pagina no menu
                "activeSubTag" => "Documentação" //Tag de ativar a pagina no menu
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function makeDocument(Request $request)
    {
        $filePbit = $request->file("pbit_file");

        if (empty($filePbit)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

```php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I search the solution in stack overflow, but see when php.ini is 2mb and no 0kbs in error message;
I changed several options in `php.ini`, the ones I found in other questions;

thanks

Comment: What's the apache post_max_size set to?

Comment: in phpinfo() post_max_size | 100M | 100M

Comment: hmm, do you have any overrides in .htaccess?

Comment: I edited question with my htaccess, thanks for help